# Mapping (Query) a function at multiple locations in nested data via All, Span

Tags: list-manipulation, associations, query

For this data:

```
dt = <|"a"-> <|"x"-> 1|>,"b"-> <|"y"-> 2|>,"c"-> <|"z"->3|>|>
```

It’s awkward when mapping the same function to multiple locations:

```
dt // Query[{"a" -> {"x" -> Framed}}]
```

When applying the same function at multiple sites, syntax gets long:

```
dt // Query[{"a" -> {"x" -> Framed}}] // Query[{"b" -> {"y" -> Framed}}]
```

In larger datasets the problem compounds. Is there a workaround for shortcuts like this:

```
dt // Query[{All -> {All -> Framed}}]
```

And also with Lists, and Span

```
dt // Query[{All -> {(1;;2) -> Framed}}]
```

as well as with hybrids of List and Associations.

PS - Even the nested parentheses are a pain for deeply nested data (we routinely deal with 6 levels or more), mitigated by this helper:

```
queryAt[seq__] := Query[Fold[Rule /* Reverse /* List, Reverse[{seq}]]];
```

eg

```
 queryAt["a", "x", Framed]
```

Comment: `dt // Query[All, All, Framed]` should work.

Comment: @JHM, only in the special case where it's mapped to `All` leaves, versus at specific branches, eg `dt // Query["a", All, Framed]` projects out the other branches.

Comment: `MapAt[Framed, {"a", "x"}]@dt`

Comment: @chuy, I don't want to mention `"x"` explicitly. This will also work `MapAt[Framed, {{"a", "x"}, {"b", "y"}}]@dt` but need it to work across a Span or All keys at lower level.

Comment: @Kuba, help me rephrase Q if necessary, but it's not about dropping a bracket - `queryAt` does that. It's about substituting `All` or `Span` instead of named keys.

Comment: `MapAt[Framed, {"a", All}]@dt`, check out the doc for `MapAt`

Comment: @chuy, that last one works with `All` but not with `Span`: try `MapAt[Framed, 1 ;; 2]`

Comment: @Kuba, my fault, meant: `dt // Query[{"a" -> {"x" -> Framed}}] // 
 Query[{"b" -> {"y" -> Framed}}]` , so single association. Will edit Q

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Replace` and `Tuples` to expand a `Part` specification in `MapAt` so it behaves as needed with `Span`.

```
expandedPart[rules__] :=
 Tuples[Replace[{Span[r__] :> Range[r], (t_ /; Head[t] =!= List) -> List[t]}] /@ {rules}]
```

This expands a `Part` specification.

```
expandedPart[1 ;; 3 ;; 2, All]
(* {{1, All}, {3, All}} *)
```

Now with `MapAt`

```
MapAt[Framed, expandedPart[1 ;; 3 ;; 2, All]]@dt
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or

```
MapAt[Framed, expandedPart[{"a", "c"}, All]]@dt
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: @alancalvitti Note that relative from end specifications like `-4;;-2` will work with the above but not open mixed relative from start and end like `;;-2` or `1;;-2`.