# Bug with MapAt, Span, and Association?

Tags: bugs, associations

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 11.0.0**

---

Related to [Mapping (Query) a function at multiple locations in nested data via All, Span](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/116479/121), it seems to me that the behavior of [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) with [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html) in 10.1.0, applied to an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html), has a bug:

```
asc = <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>;

MapAt[f, asc, 1 ;; 2]

(* out=  <|"a" -> f[1], "b" -> f[2]|>             *)
```

I think it should evaluate the same as:

```
MapAt[f, asc, {{1}, {2}}]

(* out=  <|"a" -> f[1], "b" -> f[2], "c" -> 3|>   *)
```

Do others agree that the disappearance of key "c" is a bug, and which versions are affected?

Comment: Definitely looks like a bug to me, I have filed a report.

Comment: @ilian Thanks, and thanks.  Shall I presume versions 10.0 through 10.4 are affected?

Comment: Yes, goes back to 10.0.0 and still present today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in the just released [Mathematica 11.0](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-11/):

```
MapAt[f, <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>, 1 ;; 2]

(* <|"a" -> f[1], "b" -> f[2], "c" -> 3|> *)
```